# Modify users based on Office location

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I can't get this to work... any ideas? Basically, even if a user is in Chicago, the claim is the user isn't and falls in the else statement.

I basically want to collect all users in AD.

Then I want to look at their Office location and based on where they are located, set their address....

```
 $Users = Get-ADGroupMember "Domain Users" -recursive | Select-Object sAMAccountName

foreach ($User in $Users)
{
if 
(Get-ADUser -filter {saMAccountName -eq '$User' -and Office -eq "Chicago"})
{
Set-ADUser -StreetAddress "66 Chicago Rd" -City "Chicago" -PostalCode "60618" -State "IL" -Country "US"  -Replace @{ co="United States"; countryCode="804" }
}
else
{
(echo $User " not in Chicago!")}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this :

```
$Users = Get-ADGroupMember "Domain Users" -recursive | Select-Object sAMAccountName

foreach ($User in $Users)
{
if 
(Get-ADUser -filter {saMAccountName -eq $User.saMAccountName -and Office -eq "Chicago"})
{
Set-ADUser -StreetAddress "66 Chicago Rd" -City "Chicago" -PostalCode "60618" -State "IL" -Country "US"  -Replace @{ co="United States"; countryCode="804" }
}
else
{
(echo $User " not in Chicago!")}
}
```

I just replace

```
saMAccountName -eq '$User'
```

by

```
saMAccountName -eq $User.saMAccountName
```

Comment: Or just change the original `Select-Object` to `Select-Object -Expand ...`.  The problem is that you are using `$User` as a string, but it is really a `PSObject`, so you get "@{SamAccountName=<USER>}" as the literal value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for some reason $obj.Property is not expanded in the filter scriptblock. I used Foreach-Object instead of Select-Object to extract the values of sAMAccountName. You were also missing the user object to set in the Set-ADUser command:

```
$Users = Get-ADGroupMember "Domain Users" -recursive | Foreach-Object {$_.sAMAccountName}

foreach ($User in $Users)
{
    if (Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountName -eq $User -and Office -eq 'Chicago'})
    {
        $user | Set-ADUser -StreetAddress '66 Chicago Rd' -City Chicago -PostalCode 60618 -State IL -Country US  -Replace @{ co='United States'; countryCode=804 }
    }
    else
    {
        "$User  not in Chicago!"
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

You can also use the streaming nature of the cmdlets in question (process one object at a time) with the following one-liner:

```
Get-ADGroupMember 'Domain Users' -Recursive | Where-Object {$_.ObjectClass -eq 'user'} | Get-ADUser -Properties Office | Where-Object {$_.Office -eq 'Chicago'} | Set-ADUser -StreetAddress '66 Chicago Rd' -City Chicago -PostalCode 60618 -State IL -Country US  -Replace @{ co='United States'; countryCode=804 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out... but how would I do multiple locations? For example I have 20 locations / addresses. That only allows me to do Chicago? This is in reference to your update.

Comment: Ok.. one quick question with this. the if statement I have... I seem to filter it down to one user.. is that efficient with 2000+ user objects alone? Is there a better method to do this? IE Grab all users into a collection then go through each user somehow instead of using the filter down method by sAMAccountName?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to query the domain users group? I would go with a filter query of {office -eq 'chicago'} and update them accordingly. That will save an extra query for each user with Get-ADUser. If you need to set different addresses for different offices use a switch statement.

Comment: I actually updated it to be this instead of Domain users. $Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * | Foreach-Object {$_.sAMAccountName}, works the same...

Comment: What I meant is something like: Get-ADUser -Filter {Office -eq 'Chicago'} | Set-ADUser ...